# how to use ajax for dropdowm in yii

Tags: yii

how to use ajax call for drop down in yii..i have 1dropdown and 1textfield..if the user selects one item from drop down then automatically textfield have to fill data from database..can any one help me..

```html
 <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Seattype'); ?>
 <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'seattype',
     array('S' => 'Sleeper', 'M' => 'Semi-sleeper','A'=>'Seater'),
              array('empty' => '(Select Type)','name'=>'seattype'));?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'seattype'); ?>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'amount'); ?>
 <?php echo $form->textField($model,'amount',array('name'=>'amount','id'=>'amount')); ?>
 <?php echo $form->error($model,'amount'); ?>
 </div>
   
</div>
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit',array('name'=>'submit'))?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this script,

```
<script>
 $('#seattype').on('change',function()
    {
            var selected_val = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url:   '<?php echo $this->createUrl('your_controller/your_action');?>',
                  data:  {id: selected_val},
                  success: function( amt){
                     $('#amount').val(amt);  //set returned amount value from controller
                    },
                  error: function(){
                     alert('failure');
                  }
                });

    });
</script>
```

sample controller action with hardcoded value,

```
public function actiongetAmount()
{
  if($_POST['id'] == 'S')
  echo 500;
  else if($_POST['id'] == 'M')
  echo 1000;
  else 
  echo 100;
}
```

Comment: which controller action you want perform in dropdown onchange, syntax, $this->createUrl('your_action_name'),

Comment: are you okay with this?

Comment: no here i am using two tables one to store these values and another one to load the data for amount..is ther any possible without using ajax

Comment: i don't understand, what you store in one table? and what you load from another table?

Comment: actually what i want is if the user selects the sleeper option in the amount field it will load 500 automatically for this what i do

Comment: do you have controller method to get amount value from database?

Comment: i have updated my answer just call your controller action and echo the amount from there, in success set that value in amount field